# In maven pom.xml, how to specify that I want to copy a ".xml" file into my target folder?

Tags: java, maven, copy, pom.xml, mybatis

I'm building a mybatis project, under my src/main/java I have folder structure like this:

```
java
--mypackage
    --beans
        UserBean.java
    --mapper
        UserMapper.java
        UserMapper.xml
    --service
        UserMapperServer.java
--resources
```

when I run "mvn compile", the java files will be compiled into "target/classes" folder, but my "UserMapper.xml" file is not automatically copied into "target/classes/mypackage/mapper" folder, so the program will fail to start/debug.

If I move the file into "resources" folder, then "mvn compile" copies it into "target/classes" folder, but not "target/classes/mypackage/mapper" folder, still not able to run/start.

So my question is, in "pom.xml" how to specify my required "copy" file instruction?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you create the directory `resources/mypackager/mapper` and put the XML file there it will be copied into `target/classes/mypackager/mapper`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maven convention suggests putting the sources into `src/main/resources` folder

In this case maven will pick them an put to jar automatically, no need to use `src/main/java` for this.

Now, `resources` folder can also have inner folders

So, your layout should be (to comply with maven conventions):

```
java
--mypackage
    --beans
        UserBean.java
    --mapper
        UserMapper.java         
    --service
        UserMapperServer.java
--resources
resources
--mypackage
    --mapper
         UserMapper.xml
```